# Laravel Relationships setup for the following table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am trying to set up a exam timetable module, 
This is the table structure:-

```
id
title
start_date
end_date
class_id
subject_id
date(for each subject_id)
```

Now the thing is that class_id exists in classroom table as "id" and I need to get it's name from it which is in the table as "title". Similarly for the subject_id where it exists in subject table as "id" and it's name which is in the table as "title". Once I get these the database table would look something like this:-

```
id      title           start_date          end_date        class_id        subject_id  date
1       test            some_date           some_date           1           1       date
1       test            some_date           some_date           1           2       date
1       test            some_date           some_date           1           3       date
1       test            some_date           some_date           1           4       date
```

how do I set up my controller with the relationships, please help!

Comment: Start by reading the documentation on [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships). There are loads of examples. Come back if you have any specific questions.

Comment: I have already asked my specific question @fubar

Comment: you can check the text in between the tables for the question, also is there any better method for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
In exam model.

```
public function class()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Class');
}
public function subject()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Subject');
}
```

In class model.

```
  public function exam()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject');
}
```

In subject model

```
  public function exam()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject');
}
```

This way, you can perform

```
 return $exam->subject->title
```

or

```
 return $exam->class->title
```

but if you have relationship between class and subject already, you can achieve this in another way using belongs to through  which you can find here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: hey @ashish in the class model shouldn't it be belongsTo('App\Exam') and similarly for subject model. please let me know if I am wrong

Comment: That's correct if you want to have relationship between class and subject as well.

Comment: I want some more help but my questions get downvoted here, can we connect somewhere else?
https://facebook.com/geekshubh 
can you send me a friend request?